# How to use SharedPreferences

Tags: android

I study Java one week only. Please tell me how to save the last working activity in Java. I just know what to use SharedPreferences .For example:

We have three activities (1.java, 2.java, 3.java), 1.java - has a filter, with the LAUNCHER category. The user from 1.java moved to 2.java, then "completely exited the application" (onDestroy). And after a while, he enters it, and he is thrown to where he was last time, and this is 2.java. The question is how to implement it?

```
I've looked all over YouTube and the internet. I asked questions on various forums, but all to no avail. Because everyone writes about saving when turning, saving text, etc.
```

Comment: `Please tell me how to save the last working activity in Java.` One can not save activities in Java. One cannot save activities in shared preferences. One can save string values in shared preferences. For instance "exit=activity2". It is pretty unclear if you dont know how to save a string and get it back at restart, or whatever.

Comment: @blackapps, I'm newbie, sorry

Comment: Dont say sorry. Instead explain what you need better. You did not react on what i said at all.

Comment: And, Jawa made motorcycles. In  Prague, Czechoslovakia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SharedPreferences object points to a file containing key-value pairs and provides simple methods to read and write them. Each SharedPreferences file is managed by the framework and can be private or shared. This page shows you how to use the SharedPreferences APIs to store and retrieve simple values.

Comment: Where, sorry, I do not see

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).